swiper returns to previous slide when rendering component data
Assume two swiper slides. Slide1 and Slide2. In slide 1 I show a button that generates data, that data should be shown in slide2 but when that series of data is generated, when printed on slide2 it immediately returns to slide1
.ts file
dispatchPayment(info: any, dn: any): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.store.dispatch(new GenerateAcion({ info, dn }));
      this.store.select(PaymentState.paymentStatus).subscribe(state => {
        if (state.paymentSuccess) {
          const result = {}
          resolve(result);
        } else if (state.paymentError) {
          reject(state.paymentError);
        }
      });
    });
  }

 async generarCupon() {
    const payload = ...
    const dn = ...
    try {
      const result = await this.dispatchPayment(payload, dn);
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
      if(result){
    console.log("result", result);
        this.swiper.slideTo(3, 1000);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('failed:', error);
    }
  }

.html file
<div class="modal-outer">
    <swiper-container
      (afterinit)="swiperReady()"
      #slider
      allow-touch-move="false"
      [stopOnLastSlide]="true"
      [loop]="false"
    >

     <swiper-slide style="min-height: 500px;">
            <div class="modal-wrap">
            <ion-button fill="solid" shape="round" color="success" (click)="generarCupon()">
                Generate
            </ion-button>
        </div>
    </swiper-slide>
     <swiper-slide>
            <div class="modal-wrap">
                    <div class="refrece-input">
                        <ion-label>Reference</ion-label>
                        <ion-input type="number" value="{{finalResult?.referencia}}" readonly style="font-size: 18px"></ion-input>
                    </div>
            <div class="price-detail">
                            <span>Monto</span>
                            <h2>$ {{finalResult?.costo}} <span>MXN</span></h2>
                    </div>
        </div>
    </swiper-slide>
    </swiper-container>
</div>

Current behavior: When you press the first slide button, it goes to the next slide and immediately returns to the previous one.
Expected behavior: When the button is pressed, it shows the data obtained normally

I thick you are using wrong index. When you click button on slide 1 (index 0), you should swipe to slide 2 (index 1). this.swiper.slideTo(1, 1000);

You are right, I changed the index anyway but the problem persists

can you make stackblitz with minimal reproducible?
